# Bayesian logistic regression using rjags

Tags: r, rjags

I want to perform Bayesian logistic regression using package `rjags`. Unfortunately I end up being frustrated with an error msg

```
Error parsing model file: syntax error on line 9 near ")
```

which I can't interpret. Can anyone help. I am new to stack overflow and bear with me in case I breach the rules.

My codes are:

```
merged2<-read.csv("merged2.csv")
head(merged2,2)
####Defining values that will be used
N1<-length(merged2$V190)

####Preparing dat for JAGS
dat<-list("N1"=N1,"perinatal"=merged2$perinatal,"V025"=merged2$V025,"V190"=merged2$V190,"V106"=merged2$V106,"V212"=merged2$V212,"B11"=merged2$B11)
####Initial values
inits1.jags<-list(beta=0.0)

####Define the JAGS model
mod.jags<-"model{
                
                #Likelihood
                for (i in 1:N){
                perinatal[i]~dbern(q[i])
                logit(q[i])<-beta[1]+beta[2]*V190[i,1]+beta[3]*V212[i,2]+beta[4]*V106[i,3]+beta[5]*V025[i,4]+beta[6]*B11[i,5]
                }
                #Priors
                for (j in 1:6){
                beta[j]~dnorm(0.001,)
                }
                }"
                

####Set up the JAGS model
model<-jags.model(textConnection(mod.jags),data = dat,n.chains = 2,quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. You could for example post parts of your data with `dput(head(merged2))`.

Comment: Are you sure there is a comma after value in `dnorm`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you need to set the precision for `dnorm(0.001, Tau)` where `tau <-pow(1,-2)` or whatever makes sense in your context